# Less approach for hover and active together

Tags: less, mixins

Why the following css is not getting applied on active and focus state of the button. Is this less apparoach wrong?

```css
.baseBorderButton{
 box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
 border-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
}

.noBorder{
 &:extend(baseBorderButton);
    width:@full-width;
    min-width: 80%;
 .Padding(0);
    height: auto;
    min-height: 36px;
 &:hover{
  &:extend(baseBorderButton);
  background-color:@somecolor;
 }
 &:focus,&:active,&:active:focus,
 .focus,&:active.focus{
  &:extend(baseBorderButton);
  background-color: @somecolor;
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo/understanding error. The parameter to the `:extend()` function should be a full selector and so you have to give it along with the `.` (like `&:extend(.baseBorderButton)`)

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got it :) I fixed it by  noticing it :)

Comment: Also `&:extend(baseBorderButton);` in `&:hover, &:focus, &:etc` rulesets are redudand since they are already inherit all properties of the `.noBorder`.